# How to capture pictures using volume button expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

All the libraries available online require native dependencies. Is there a way to capture photos using volume button using expo framework in react native.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible currently.
As of now, you cannot add listeners to hardware keys if you develop the react-native application with Expo.

The feature is yet to be added. 
https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/hardware-keys-api-volume-updown-power-button